# trying to only obtain certain columns with their headers but all column headers selected

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

```
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
include('watermark1.php');
$number = $_COOKIE["user"]; 
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT Employee_number,date_start,date_end,Days_taken,Sick,Study,Annual,compassionate_leave,Other,Details,Status,approved_by FROM leave_management WHERE Employee_Number='$number'");
```

The problem is here because i dont know how to write the code to only get the headers of the selected query from above and instead it pulls all the headers from the table instead of only the selected column headers. any hint on how to amend the $header code ?

```
$header = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='Namtax' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='leave_management'");
```

Comment: Get the headers from $result rather than from a separate query against the information schema

Comment: do you by chance now the code to do that ? Mark Baker

Comment: If you return the row as an associative array, then the keys are your headings